# How to accept both touch events and mouse events to detect when a control has been clicked?

Tags: eclipse, swt

I have made a virtual keyboard which works fine when using a mouse. However, I am having difficulty getting it to work properly on a touch screen.

For normal operation it works ok. I press the screen and release. This raises a `MouseDown` event followed by a `MouseUp` event. This is ok.

I then wanted to add a popup on a key which is trigged by pressing and holding for 500ms. With a mouse this is not a problem but I now see that the mouse events triggered by a touch are only raised **after** the touch is released. There is no possibility to trigger the popup up after a delay.

Next I added `TouchListener`s to the virtual keys and thought the problem is solved until I realised that the mouse events still get raised causing 2 'key' presses - one from the touch and one from the mouse.

I would like to keep both options open so that either the touch screen can be used or the mouse. So my question is: how can I prevent the mouse events being raised if I have already handled the events using the `TouchListener`?

(Using eclipse kepler with Java7 on Windows 10)

```
TouchListener touchListener = new TouchListener() {
    boolean down = false;
    @Override
    public void touch(TouchEvent e) {
        for (Touch t : e.touches) {
            if(t.primary) {
                if((t.state & SWT.TOUCHSTATE_DOWN) == SWT.TOUCHSTATE_DOWN) {
                    if(!down) {
                        down = true;
                        onKeyDown();
                    }
                }
                if((t.state & SWT.TOUCHSTATE_UP) == SWT.TOUCHSTATE_UP) {
                    if(down) {
                        down = false;
                        onKeyUp();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
MouseAdapter mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
        onKeyDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) {
        onKeyUp();
    }
};

Label myKey = new Label(panel, 0);
myKey.setTouchEnabled(true);
myKey.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
myKey.addTouchListener(touchListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easiest to handle this at a higher level, as a debounce. If you get two onKeyUp() events from one key within a very short time, ignore the second. (Use the Event.time field rather than the time when you process the event)